# VSCode: search classes / go to class for imported libraries

Tags: class, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

What is the VSCode equivalent to IntelliJ's **Go to class** ? I.e. I want to type in the class name and receive a pop-up list of all the classes that match my pattern. However, these should include not-only my project's classes but also **imported libraries' classes**.

InteliJ has an option "Include non-project items" when you look for classes using `⌘ + O` or `ctrl+O`.

The language I'm using is: Dart.

[image]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try using [go to symbol in workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name) (bound to <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> by default). This should be implemented by dart and other language extensions.

It's up to each extension to determine how this feature works. JS/TS includes symbols from imported libraries for example, but this behavior may differ between extensions

Comment: `Ctrl + T` in case you're on Linux.

Comment: @BrunoGelb Or Windows

Comment: I'm on Linux and `Ctrl + T` appears to do something GIt related

Answer (score 8):

A bit late, but you can use `Ctrl+P` to search by file name [image]

that's only usable if your class names match the file name though.
I'd like to see one day vscode SymbolSearch system accept some special filters ( like in Visual Studio where `t [class name]` searchs only class names)

Comment: File name is not helpful when you have a fully qualified class name and no easy way to jump to the class definition

Comment: Unfortunately that's as far as vscode can go for now. I don't really miss the option though because file names are usually the same as the class name in most of the projects i work on. but yeah, still, would not work if thats not the case